# Power BI/SSRS Parameter Hierarchy Issue - Default Values Being Deleted Instead of Resetting

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am encountering an issue in Power BI where changing a parameter at a higher hierarchy level results in the default values of subordinate parameters being deleted instead of resetting to their default values. Here is a simplified example of my parameter setup:

I have three parameters: **Main Product Group** (All, Food, and Drinks), **Product Group** (All, Chips, Sweets, Alcohol, Non-alcohol), and **Product** (All, Paprika Chips, Chocolate, Beer 0.5L, Fanta). The default values for all parameters are set to **All**.

Here's what I tried:

I selected "Food" in the Main Product Group parameter.
The Product Group parameter correctly displayed only the options "All," "Chips," and "Sweets," as expected.
I then selected "Chips" in the Product Group parameter.
Subsequently, I switched to "Drinks" in the Main Product Group parameter.
What I expected to happen:

I anticipated that when changing the Main Product Group parameter to "Drinks" after selecting "Chips" in the Product Group parameter, the default values in the Product parameter would be reset to "All."

What actually resulted:

Instead of resetting to "All," the default values in the Product parameter were deleted.

My expectation is that when transitioning to a higher-level category (e.g., from "Chips" in Product Group to "Drinks" in Main Product Group), the lower-level parameter (Product) should revert to its default values rather than being cleared entirely.

How can I ensure that the Product parameter, when switching from Product Group to Drinks in Main Product Group, resets to All instead of being deleted?

Thank you!